# 5 cards are drawn from well shuffled deck of cards (without replacement) .What is the probability that three of them are between 5 to 7?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, card-games

5 cards are drawn from well shuffled deck of cards (without replacement) .What is the probability that three of them are between 5 to 7?
probability probability-theory combinations
If the question asked about only 3 of them are between 5 to 7 then the answer is easy it will be $$
\frac{\binom{12}{3}\binom{40}{2}}{\binom{52}{5}}.
$$
But here it is different I thought of the following two answers

$12/52 * 11/51 * 10/50 *1 =11/1105$ Since it doesn't matter what other 2 cards are but since the order doesn't matter we must divided the above by 3! So the answer = 11/6630 which equal to $12C3/(52 * 51 *50)$

$(12C3*49C2)/52C5 =22/221$ because I think the answer must has 52C5 as it denominator.

Comment: Please take cases where there are $3$ cards between $5-7$, $4$ cards between $5-7$ and $5$ cards between $5-7$.

Comment: Please format your equations with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) by clicking the edit button. I did one for you to get started.

Comment: When nothing has been *explicitly* specified, how do you know whether the question is of the *exactly* type or the *at least* type ? Do you have some inside information ?

Comment: I think that it's usual to construe it as *at least* three if it doesn't say one way or the other.  Certainly if four of the cards are between $5$ and $7$ then three of them are.

Comment: @coffeemath: It happens to me all the time ! I deleted the observation.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i have understood , you want to say three of five cards are in $[5-7]$ and two of five cards are not in $[5-7]$. This means that $\color{blue}{exactly}$ three cards in $[5-7]$.

Lets call the cards between $[5-7]$ as $\color{red}{A}$ and the others as $\color{green}{B}$. To determine their selection order , we should arrange $\color{red}{A,A,A}$$\color{green}{,B,B}$ . We can do it by $$\frac{5!}{2! \times 3!}=10$$

Moreover , question say that no replacements . Then ,we know that there are $12$ different cands in $[5-7]$. We can assign them to $\color{red}{A,A,A}$ by $P(12,3)$ ways . The rest is done by $P(40,2)$ ways.

The denominator will be $P(52,5)$ instead of $C(52,5)$ because there is not any replacement and when we select each card , the total number of cards will be selected  are going to decrease by one by.

CASE II-) If there are at least $3$ cards in $[5-7]$ , then :

Subcase I-)Lets call the cards between $[5-7]$ as $\color{red}{A}$ and the others as $\color{green}{B}$. To determine their selection order , we should arrange $\color{red}{A,A,A}$$\color{green}{,B,B}$ . We can do it by $$\frac{5!}{2! \times 3!}=10$$

Moreover , question say that no replacements . Then ,we know that there are $12$ different cands in $[5-7]$. We can assign them to $\color{red}{A,A,A}$ by $P(12,3)$ ways . The rest is done by $P(40,2)$ ways.

The denominator will be $P(52,5)$ instead of $C(52,5)$ because there is not any replacement and when we select each card , the total number of cards will be selected  are going to decrease by one by.

Subcase II-) There are $4$ desired card and $1$ undesired card such that :

Lets call the cards between $[5-7]$ as $\color{red}{A}$ and the others as $\color{green}{B}$. To determine their selection order , we should arrange $\color{red}{A,A,A,A}$$\color{green}{,B}$ . We can do it by $$\frac{5!}{1! \times 4!}=5$$

We can assign them to $\color{red}{A,A,A,A}$ by $P(12,4)$ ways . The rest is done by $P(40,1)$ ways.

The denominator will be $P(52,5)$ instead of $C(52,5)$ because there is not any replacement and when we select each card , the total number of cards will be selected  are going to decrease by one by.

Subcase III-)Lets call the cards between $[5-7]$ as $\color{red}{A}$ and the others as $\color{green}{B}$. To determine their selection order , we should arrange $\color{red}{A,A,A,A,A}$ . We can do it by $$\frac{5!}{5!}=1$$

Moreover , question say that no replacements . Then ,we know that there are $12$ different cands in $[5-7]$. We can assign them to $\color{red}{A,A,A,A,A}$ by $P(12,5)$ ways .

The denominator will be $P(52,5)$ instead of $C(52,5)$ because there is not any replacement and when we select each card , the total number of cards will be selected  are going to decrease by one by.

$\color{blue}{RESULT=}$ $$(\frac{5!}{2! \times 3!} \times \frac {P(12,3) \times P(40,2)}{P(52,5)})  + (\frac{5!}{1! \times 4!} \times \frac {P(12,4) \times P(40,1)}{P(52,5)}) + (\frac{5!}{5!} \times \frac {P(12,5) }{P(52,5)}) = 0.0739495... $$